# conditional binding of date to <asp:TableCell>

Tags: asp.net, datalist

i have a asp:TableCell and want to bind date to this on the basis of condition such that if date is DateTime.MinValue it should display empty value else the date.

i want solution in asp.net(3.5) C#.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can just set the value in the code behind, then it's very easy.

```
this.myTableCell.text = yourDate > DateTime.MinValue ? yourDate : "";
```

If not setable explicitly in the code behind, you could simply bind to a C# property or method.
Example

ASPX - your table cell `<asp:TableCell Text="<%= MyDate() %>" .../>`

```
C# Code Behind ----  this could be a property with get / set accessors or a method
public string MyDate() 
{ 
  DateTime myDateTime = GetDateTime();
  return myDateTime > DateTime.MinValue ? myDateTime.ToString() : "";
}
```

Does this provide a compass to get you started in the right direction?